# GNS3 Ubuntu VM has no network connectivity, even after trying to set static IP

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization

GNS3 Version: GNS3 v2.2.9
Operating System: Windows 10
VirtualBox 6.1.32
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

GNS3 setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDQ90.jpg

Right now I am literally just trying to get pings going between Machine2 and Observium, but I just get 'network is unreachable'. I tried to set a static IP in /etc/netplan/99_config.yaml but I had to hand-type it as I can't seem to copy-paste into the VM.

My file is named *99_config.yaml* as per this link https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration but elsewhere I see others refer to the file being called *01-netcfg.yaml*.

Here is what I have in the config file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE4Ae.jpg

Here is the output from `ip addr`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA4yn.jpg

`dmesg` says enp0s3 was renamed from eth0; not sure if that is important: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMjO5.jpg

The NIC for the VM is initially set to 'unattached', but is then shown like this when GNS3 is controlling it - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTGDH.jpg - that seems to be fine AFAIK.

Any help please? TIA!

Edit: I can see the results from `ip route show` have now changed from what they were previously (that wasn't returning anything at all, before) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIt71.jpg It says 'default via 192.168.15.1', which is the switch, so I don't know why it still can't ping it?

Edit: the config is like

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.15.2/24
      gateway4: 192.168.15.1
      nameservers:
          search: [mydomain, otherdomain]
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

But as mentioned I am unable to copy-paste to/from the VM so far.

Edit: I managed to get IPs set for 2 of 3 interfaces on ESW1, but the other one wouldn't work as it came back 'IP addresses may not be configured on L2 links'. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuxNp.jpg

Edit2: I tried bringing the interface down before configuring it, but just got "ip addresses may not be configured on l2 links"

Edit3: OK, I think maybe I have at least got the ESW1 switch set up now? I tried to add a screenshot but the site won't let me. :(

Edit4: I set machine 2 to IP 192.168.16.2, and the interface of the switch that it is connected to to 192.168.16.4, and can ping that OK, but that is the only ping I can get working right now.

Edit5: I have my switch set up as follows:

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
FastEthernet0/0            192.168.15.5    YES manual up                    up
FastEthernet0/1            192.168.20.3    YES manual up                    up
FastEthernet1/0            192.168.16.4    YES manual up                    up
```

I was told to add IP routing to the switch to enable inter-vlan routing. Apparently I disabled the "switchport" or layer 2 functionality on the ports, so they are now layer 3 ports. I was told layer 3 switching does not by default allow for intervlan switching.

'no switchport' didn't work though:

```
Router(config)#interface FastEthernet0/0 no switchport
                                         ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Router(config)#interface FastEthernet0/1 no switchport
                                         ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Router(config)#int FastEthernet0/1 no switchport
                                   ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Router(config)#interface FastEthernet0/0
Router(config-if)#no switchport
                      ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

At this point I can ping the switch from either VM. So the issue has surely got to be with the switch.

Edit6: the only thing I can see that looks possibly incorrect is that in my console, the prompt is shown as `Router(config-if)#`, whereas in an example I looked at, it showed `Switch(config-if)#`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question and copy&paste all text *as text*, formatted as code blocks.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I did say in the OP - I'm unable to copy-paste from the VM. I don't know why as I've enabled the setting for the VM, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The gateway should not be your switch, but rather your router. And the switch wouldn't normally be at .1 anyway. Please fix and report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema - OK, I set the gateway to the IP of the router. The switch doesn't seem to have any IPs set at all though, so I don't know what happened to the ones I thought I set yesterday? I still can't get any pings working. `ip route show` returns `192.168.15.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.15.2` https://i.imgur.com/bG2Ru3t.jpg https://i.imgur.com/sP8BuZL.jpg

Comment: Your VM/network configs are over my head. Sorry.